# Android, accessing methods between classes

Tags: java, android

I have an application that is pretty much now complete, however I have several methods within the main class so it looks very untidly/large.

I want to separate these methods out into separate classes but despite me trying this I continually get null pointer errors.

Even when creating just a string within another class and trying to obtain that within another I am getting null results.

I have done a search on here but nothing really answers my questions, I would appreciate some help.

Edit: here is some example code:

```
public  class Test2  extends mainClass{
public ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> somethingz = new ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem>();
public void addSomething() {
    ExtendedOverlayItem poi = new ExtendedOverlayItem(
            "description", "description", new GeoPoint(88.123058,
                    -10.987654), null);
    poi.setMarkerHotspot(OverlayItem.HotspotPlace.CENTER);
    poi.setDescription("test");
    somethingz.add(poi);

    ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> node = new ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem>(
            this, somethingz, map);
    map.getOverlays().add(node);

}
public ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> getSomethingz() {
    return somethingz;
}
public Test2(ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> somesthingz) {
    super();
    this.somesthingz =somesthingz;

}
public void setSomethingz(ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> somesthingz) {
    this.somesthingz = somesthingz;
}

}
```

Then in my main class I have simply added

Test2 test;
Then called the method with: test.addSomething();

I am most likely missing something trivial, but I have even just tried this with a string in the test2 class then attempting to print it out from the main class but it results in null pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you accessing the fields of the other class? Are they static or instance fields? Are you instantiating objects correctly? Pay attention to the scope.

Comment: can you post an example of what you are trying to do currently? It might make it easier to advise as to what the problem is.

Comment: You should post a relevant piece of code and some LogCat literature, otherwise no one will be able to answer you and your question will be closed.

Comment: Updated original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you are maybe trying to do this:

```
Test2 test;
test.addSomething();
```

If so, then you need to instantiate the object like so:

```
ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> itemList = new ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem>();
Test2 test = new Test2(itemList);
test.addSomething();
```

Take a look at some of the various [introductory Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) out there to get familiar with the language.

Comment: If that is the case, how can I accomplish the line:Test2 test = new Test2(); As I would have to have to use Test2's constructor: public Test2(ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> somethingz) {

Comment: I updated the answer. Please go read that Java language tutorial.

Comment: Ok I have now got all of this to work but have a few other problems to look into, thanks.

Comment: Have done, and also fixed my other problems. Thanks again for the advice.